# How to allow some other person to access my bank (or PayPal) account in some emergency?

Tags: bank-account, paypal, emergency-fund, death

I was thinking in a situation for example like an accident, resulting in a coma or something like that.
Is it possible to allow someone else to manage our bank or PayPal accounts in that case?

Comment: Are you looking for technical mechanisms (sharing credentials when certain things happen) or legal mechanisms (springing and durable power of attorney)?

Comment: I don't want to share my credentials (or maybe yes but if there is a way to limit the access only in case of emergency). I think then is more a legal power, but again, only in case of emergency

Comment: A password manager with the master password written down somewhere safe (e.g. a safe deposit box in a bank).

Comment: Possibly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_attorney#Durable_power_of_attorney

Comment: I was expecting some service or feature already implemented in the bank or at least Paypal, I mean, should be something as easy to leave a name right? going with a lawyer sounds a bit complex

Comment: @Enrique: You don't need a lawyer to establish a power of attorney.  You can buy kits with forms for your location (or the location where your bank is headquartered) and fill in the blanks, then sign with an appropriate witness (usually a notary).  You want the form for springing and durable power of attorney.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK you can declare one or more persons your [Lasting power of attorney](https://www.gov.uk/lasting-power-attorney-duties).

From the .gov.uk website

> The person who appoints you is called the ‘donor’. You’re their ‘attorney’.
>
> You don’t need any legal experience to act as someone’s attorney.
>
> The types of decisions you make depend on whether you’re a:
>
> - property and financial affairs attorney
> - health and welfare attorney

You can appoint multiple attorneys and even specify if they must come to a joint decision or if one person can make a decision on their own.

[The role of a financial affairs attorney](https://www.gov.uk/lasting-power-attorney-duties/property-financial-affairs):

> As a property and financial affairs attorney, you make (or help the
>   donor make) decisions about things like:
>
> - money, tax and bills bank and building society accounts property and
> - investments pensions and benefits You can use the donor’s money to
> - look after their home and buy anything they need day to day (for
> - example, food).

This essentially means if you're incapacitated and unable to manage your own money, your LPA can do this for you as you describe. My grandmother did this when her father was no longer able to look after himself, it's not too difficult but a good accountant can be useful.

To appoint someone as your attorney, you need to fill out the appropriate forms and [register your LPA](https://www.gov.uk/power-of-attorney/register). It it currently costs £82 to register each type of attorney (you apply for each one separately)